# Do constructors have to initialize member variables in C++?

Tags: c++

I have learned that constructors are used to initialize the member variables of a class in C++. In all the examples I have seen the constructors initialize all the member variables of the class when called.

What happens if I write a constructor that only initializes some or none of the member variables?

Comment: It is a good idea to initialise all member variables in the order that they are declared

Comment: In my experience, the rule of thumb goes like this: when you don't need to write any constructor by yourself because all data members know how to initialise themselves, then don't anything. If you need to write at least one constructor yourself, regardless of whether you have a data member that needs some help or if you need to do something else in the constructor, then explicitly initialise all data members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what member variables you have. If you provide a constructor and don't explicitly initialize a variable in the member initialization list, then it will be [*default initialized*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). And this is for every variable.

Now, default initialization does something else depending on what variable you have. If you have a builtin type, like `int` or `bool`, then it will not be initialized to 0 or any other value, just like if you had:

```
int value; // it has an indeterminate value
```

This also applies to arrays. If it is another class, then the default constructor of that class will be called, just like if you had:

```
struct Foo { /*something*/ };
Foo value; // calls default constructor, i.e. initializes object
```

Comment: Also, it is interesting to know it can depend on compiler options. In debug mode, compilers might default-initialize variables such as pointers to specific values to help debugging (helping to pinpoint "aw, I didn't initialize this pointer"). But of course, it should not be relied on and usually disappear when compiled in release mode.

Answer (score 2):

it's fine.. you can also initialize your member variables in your member functions, then, just call the function in the constructor.. the important thing is to don't forget to initialize variables before using them..

in short.. it's fine to not initialize your member variables in the constructor as long as you initialize them somewhere in the class before using them..

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to do that. It isn't great practise though as you'll have a series of uninitialised member variables that could produce unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the class and your program. Does your class and program needs all of those variables in all of the cases. if your class does require them then no errors or exception will occur otherwise your program might crash or something.